# Initializing Firebase SDK without DatabaseURL?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

I noticed that it is possible to initialize the `Firebase SDK` using only the `service account key`.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
.build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Is `databaseUrl` optional when initializing `Firebase SDK`? If yes why is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database URL is only needed if your code uses the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), so `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`.

Comment: In case of Java, `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`.